# Tkinter button resize

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247813/7416363) I found how to resize a button, so I tried to execute this code.

```
from tkinter import * 
selection_window = Tk()
selection_window.wm_title("")
selection_window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(200, 150))
frame_1 = Frame(selection_window, width=200, height=30)
Button(frame_1, text="Single",height = 100).pack(side=LEFT,anchor=S)
Button(frame_1,text="Range",command=Toplevel,height = 20).pack(side=RIGHT,anchor=S)
frame_1.pack()
selection_window.mainloop()
```

But the size of button is not changed, rather, the buttons went to the center of the window. Can someone please tell me why is the problem?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: BTW: simpler `.geometry("200x150")`

Comment: It's an OS related issue, I'm using linux and your buttons have different heights for me. I guess that tk default theme for OSX does not support the height keyword.

Comment: @j_4321 is correct: the OSX theme is very strict about its buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Button Height:**
If you notice, the height of frame_1 is 30 and the height of the buttons are 100 and 20. One button height is significantly taller than frame_1. So if you maximise your tk window, you will see the height difference of the buttons. Alternatively, try setting one button height to 10 and the other to 2, and rerun your script, to see the height difference. Conclusion, the button heights can be changed.

**Button Lateral Placement:**
The lateral placement of the buttons can be controlled by using the *padx=[x_left, x_right]* option of the pack system. *x_left* and *x_right* denotes the horizontal external padding to be left on each side of the button in relations to it's parent. Your can read [Tk documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm) for a clearer explanation on the Packer's algorithm.

```
from tkinter import * 
selection_window = Tk()
selection_window.wm_title("")
selection_window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(200, 150))
frame_1 = Frame(selection_window, width=200, height=30)
frame_1.pack()
Button(frame_1, text="Single",height = 10).pack(side=LEFT, anchor=S, padx=[0,40])
Button(frame_1,text="Range",command=Toplevel,height = 2).pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=S, padx=[20,0])
selection_window.mainloop()
```

**Height:** [image: Height] **Placement:**[image: Placement]

**Part 2:**
Per comments below, please run below script to see if changing a ttk.Button height is even possible for OSX using 'non-default' style themes and post your finding in the comment section. It worked on my Ubuntu.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
s=ttk.Style()
print('Style themes on my system are ', s.theme_names())
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure('bb.TButton', background='white', padding=50)
b1=ttk.Button(text='Default')
b1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=S, padx=[0,40])
b2=ttk.Button(text='Custom', style='bb.TButton')
b2.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=S, padx=[20,0])
```

**padding=1**[image: padding=1] 
**padding=40**[image: padding=40]

Comment: Thank you! I think @j_4321 answered the question. I tried to change the height and width value (I even used a loop to set the height in range(20)), and nothing is changed.

Comment: @pkqxdd Thanks for letting me know the height and width options in Pack had not effect in OSX. I learned something new. May I know if the padx option made any changes to the button lateral placement? The behavior described above is what I observed for an Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Comment: @pkqxdd Your problem happened for a tk.Button. According to j_4321, the issue is with tk default theme. In this case, could you see if using a different theme would work for you? To check this, you have to use a ttk.Button with different custom theme instead. See section 47 & 48 of http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-themes.html. I have looked up if changing the ttk.Button style was possible, but could did not find the option for changing height so that's that.

Comment: @Sun Bear ttk.Button does not support the height option (see http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html), so you have to find another way around (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927386/changing-ttk-button-height-in-python)

Comment: @j_4321 Thanks for pointing out. I had assumed it was there. According to Bryan, it's really a no no to change button height for OSX. Bummer! But I am curious to know if this restriction is limited to the 'default' style theme, per your earlier comment. I have written a short script and will post it in my answer. It changes the ttk.Button height via changing the padding. *pkqxdd* could you give it a try on your OSX system to see if using the other theme styles would let you change the ttk.Button height?