# How can I set the size of a button in pixels - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Python 3, and I want to set the size of a button in pixels.

I wanted to make it width = 100 pixels, height = 30 pixels, but it didn't work.

It was much bigger than I expected.

Here's My code:

```
from tkinter import *

def background():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('1160x640')

    btn_easy = Button(root, text = 'Easy', width = 100, height = 50)
    btn_easy.place(x = 100, y = 450)

    root.mainloop()

background()
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

> You can also use the height and width options to explicitly set the
>   size. **If you display text in the button, these options define the size
>   of the button in text units**. If you display bitmaps or images instead,
>   they define the size in pixels (or other screen units). **You can
>   specify the size in pixels even for text buttons, but that requires
>   some magic. Here’s one way to do it (there are others):**
>
> ```
> f = Frame(master, height=32, width=32)
> f.pack_propagate(0) # don't shrink
> f.pack()
>
> b = Button(f, text="Sure!")
> b.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
> ```

---

```
from tkinter import *

def background():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('1160x640')

    f = Frame(root, height=50, width=50)
    f.pack_propagate(0) # don't shrink
    f.place(x = 100, y = 450)

    btn_easy = Button(f, text = 'Easy')
    btn_easy.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    root.mainloop()

background()
```

---

Bonus: many buttons (just to get the idea)

```
from tkinter import *

def sizedButton(root, x,y):

    f = Frame(root, height=50, width=50)
    f.pack_propagate(0) # don't shrink
    f.place(x = x, y = y)

    btn_easy = Button(f, text = 'Easy')
    btn_easy.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


def background():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('1160x640')

    for x in range(50,350,100):
        for y in range(50,350,100):
            sizedButton(root, x,y)


    root.mainloop()

background()
```

Comment: For other options on how to size a Button, see this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284901/how-do-i-resize-buttons-in-pixels-tkinter#comment79535257_46285846