# Is it possible to animate frames that are layed out with the grid manager in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, animation, tkinter, grid-layout

I made this desktop application with tkinter and finished the main functionalities.
But now I want to make it look better and even animate the menus is possible.
The thing is the buttons and widgets that I used are contained in frames and all of them were put by using the grid layout manageR.
So I was wondering if i could maybe animate elements ( mainly buttons and frames ) w

For an  example if I hover my mouse over a button it'll increase its size a bit, but I want of course to see the increase of that size in time. O
r maybe when I click one button and I need to change to a new frame, then the old one will slide to the right for example

Comment: "animate" is a very vague term. What sort of animation are you wanting to do?

Comment: You're right, my excuses. Well for example if I hover my mouse over a button it'll increase size a bit, but I want of course to see the increase of that size in time. Or maybe when I click one button and I need to change to a new frame, then the old one will slide to the right for example. Simple things and from there I'll continue

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: you could use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to run function with delay. If this function change widget only a little (or move it only few pixels) and it uses `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to run it again to change button again only a little (or move widget again only few pixels) then you may get "animation". But problem can be keep other elements in original place when button change size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example which use `after` to move `Frame` with `Label` and `Button`. I used `place()` to use relative position so `Frame` leave window even if you change window size.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def move(steps=10, distance=0.1):
    if steps > 0:
        # get current position
        relx = float(frame.place_info()['relx'])

        # set new position
        frame.place_configure(relx=relx+distance)

        # repeate it after 10ms
        root.after(10, move, steps-1, distance)

def on_click():
    print('on_click')
    # start move
    move(50, 0.02) # 50*0.02 = 1

# --- main --

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, background='red')
frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# to center label and button
#frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
#frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
#frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

label = tk.Label(frame, text='Frame with Label and Button')
label.grid(row=1, column=0)

button = tk.Button(frame, text='MOVE', command=on_click)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code combines some ideas for interactive buttons within a grid cell:

- callbacks `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` for mouse hovering
- a button size specified in pixels as suggested by Bryan Oakley (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286221/13257648)
- using padx/pady and width/height to control space reserved for button
- `root.after(milliseconds, function)` as suggested in furas comment

```
import tkinter as tk

buttonsize = [120, 50]
extrasize = [10, 10]
framepad = [6, 6]
anim_time = 40
anim_steps = 10

root = tk.Tk()
pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

def SizeChange(event, fraction):
    event.widget.grid_configure(padx=(1.0-fraction)*extrasize[0], pady=(1.0-fraction)*extrasize[1])
    event.widget.configure(width=buttonsize[0]+2*fraction*extrasize[0],
        height=buttonsize[1]+2*fraction*extrasize[1])
    root.update_idletasks()


def Highlight(event):
    for idx in range(anim_steps):
        fraction = float(idx+1)/anim_steps
        root.after(int(fraction*anim_time), SizeChange(event, fraction))


def Unhighlight(event):
    for idx in range(anim_steps):
        fraction = 1.0 - float(idx+1)/anim_steps
        root.after(int(fraction*anim_time), SizeChange(event, fraction))


def AddButton(row, col, name):
    tkframe = tk.Frame(root, width=buttonsize[0]+extrasize[0],
        height=buttonsize[1]+extrasize[1])
    tkframe.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=framepad[0], pady=framepad[1], sticky='nsew')
    tkbutton = tk.Button(tkframe, text=name, compound='c', image=pixel,
        width=buttonsize[0], height=buttonsize[1])
    tkbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=extrasize[0], pady=extrasize[1])
    tkbutton.bind('<Enter>', Highlight)
    tkbutton.bind('<Leave>', Unhighlight)


for idx in range(4):
    AddButton(row=idx//2, col=idx%2, name='Button ' + str(idx))


root.mainloop()
```

Although it seems the smoothness of the animation is highly dependent on the extra size added to the button size and the time steps.