# Interactive and nice looking buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I'm currently exploring Tkinter and I have a question about Button GUI. I'm looking to create a clean and simple flat button. I have discovered through the internet (mainly other StackOverflow questions) that this is achievable through creating an image button. However, is there any way that I can make these buttons more interactive by changing the image when the user is hovering over the button or changing the image on click?

thanks in advance to anyone who answers!

Comment: Use bindings. You can bind to the user pressing the button/hovering over the button. Also it wouldn't be a bad idea to check out `tkinter.ttk`.

Comment: Ah well, take a look [at this](https://github.com/nihaalnz/mtk/blob/main/mbuttons.py) it is somewhat like interactive hover buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Using `bind` will help.

```
from tkinter import *
class InterActiveButton:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("800x600")

        self.button1=Button(self.root,bg="dark blue",fg="#dad122",cursor="hand2",text="Button 1",font=("arial",18,"bold"),bd=0,activebackground="dark blue",activeforeground="#dad122")
        self.button1.place(x=10,y=10,width=200,height=50)
        self.button1.bind("<Enter>",self.on_hover)
        self.button1.bind("<Leave>",self.on_leave)
        
        self.button3=Button(self.root,bg="dark blue",fg="#dad122",cursor="hand2",text="Button 2",font=("arial",18,"bold"),bd=0,activebackground="dark blue",activeforeground="#dad122")
        self.button3.place(x=230,y=10,width=200,height=50)
        self.button3.bind("<Enter>",self.on_hover)
        self.button3.bind("<Leave>",self.on_leave)
        
        self.button3=Button(self.root,bg="dark blue",fg="#dad122",cursor="hand2",text="Button 3",font=("arial",18,"bold"),bd=0,activebackground="dark blue",activeforeground="#dad122")
        self.button3.place(x=450,y=10,width=200,height=50)
        self.button3.bind("<Enter>",self.on_hover)
        self.button3.bind("<Leave>",self.on_leave)
    def increase_width(self,ev):
        if self.done!=12:
            ev.place_configure(width=200+self.done)
            self.width_b=200+self.done
            print(self.width_b)
            self.done+=1
            self.root.after(5,lambda:self.increase_width(ev))
    def decrease_width(self,ev):
        if self.done!=12:
            ev.place_configure(width=self.width_b-1)
            self.width_b=self.width_b-1
            print("-------------")
            print(self.width_b)
            self.done+=1
            self.root.after(5,lambda:self.decrease_width(ev))
    def on_hover(self,event,*args):
        self.done=0
        event.widget['bg']="#dad122"
        event.widget['fg']="dark blue"
        #event.widget.place_configure(width=210,height=55)
        self.root.after(5,lambda: self.increase_width(event.widget))
    def on_leave(self,event,*args):
        self.done=0
        event.widget['fg']="#dad122"
        event.widget['bg']="dark blue"
        #event.widget.place_configure(width=200,height=50)
        self.root.after(5,lambda: self.decrease_width(event.widget))
        
root=Tk()
ob=InterActiveButton(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Edit by @TheLizzard:

If you want to be able to use it with any geometry manager, use this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class InterActiveButton(tk.Button):
    """
    This button expands when the user hovers over it and shrinks when
    the cursor leaves the button.

    If you want the button to expand in both directions just use:
        button = InterActiveButton(root, text="Button", width=200, height=50)
        button.pack()
    If you want the button to only expand to the right use:
        button = InterActiveButton(root, text="Button", width=200, height=50)
        button.pack(anchor="w")

    This button should work with all geometry managers.
    """
    def __init__(self, master, max_expansion:int=12, bg="dark blue",
                 fg="#dad122", **kwargs):
        # Save some variables for later:
        self.max_expansion = max_expansion
        self.bg = bg
        self.fg = fg

        # To use the button's width in pixels:
        # From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286221/11106801
        self.pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

        # The default button arguments:
        button_args = dict(cursor="hand2", bd=0, font=("arial", 18, "bold"),
                           height=50, compound="c", activebackground=bg,
                           image=self.pixel, activeforeground=fg)
        button_args.update(kwargs)
        super().__init__(master, bg=bg, fg=fg, **button_args)

        # Bind to the cursor entering and exiting the button:
        super().bind("<Enter>", self.on_hover)
        super().bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        # Save some variables for later:
        self.base_width = button_args.pop("width", 200)
        self.width = self.base_width
        # `self.mode` can be "increasing"/"decreasing"/None only
        # It stops a bug where if the user wuickly hovers over the button
        # the button doesn't go back to normal
        self.mode = None

    def increase_width(self) -> None:
        if self.width <= self.base_width + self.max_expansion:
            if self.mode == "increasing":
                self.width += 1
                super().config(width=self.width)
                super().after(5, self.increase_width)

    def decrease_width(self) -> None:
        if self.width > self.base_width:
            if self.mode == "decreasing":
                self.width -= 1
                super().config(width=self.width)
                super().after(5, self.decrease_width)

    def on_hover(self, event:tk.Event=None) -> None:
        # Improvement: use integers instead of "increasing" and "decreasing"
        self.mode = "increasing"
        # Swap the `bg` and the `fg` of the button
        super().config(bg=self.fg, fg=self.bg)
        super().after(5, self.increase_width)

    def on_leave(self, event:tk.Event=None) -> None:
        # Improvement: use integers instead of "increasing" and "decreasing"
        self.mode = "decreasing"
        # Reset the `fg` and `bg` of the button
        super().config(bg=self.bg, fg=self.fg)
        super().after(5, self.decrease_width)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

button = InterActiveButton(root, text="Button", width=200, height=50)
# Using `anchor="w"` forces the button to expand to the right.
# If it's removed, the button will expand in both directions
button.pack(padx=20, pady=20, anchor="w")

root.mainloop()
```

This also fixes the problem with the button not returning to normal if the user quickly hovers over the button.

Comment: Instead of `self.done`, why don't you just pass it as an argument when calling `self.increase_width`/`self.decrease_width`?

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I packaged the expanding button in it's own class. I also added a way for it to expand in both directions and the ability to use any geometry manager.

Comment: @TheLizzard, no problem

Answer (score 0):

To make the button change color on hover, you can try the below code. However, I would not suggest using Tkinter if you want your interface to look beautiful. Try Kivy if you can. It really helps in making a natural user interface!
Anyways, here's the code for the button to change color on hover:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
 
# Create a window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
 
# Create style Object
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton", font=("Calibri", 20, "bold"), borderwidth=4)
# Changes will be reflected
# by the movement of mouse.
style.map("TButton", foreground=[("active", "disabled", "green")],
          background=[("active", "black")])
 
# Button 1
btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Quit!", command=root.destroy)
btn1.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=100)
 
# Button 2
btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text="Click me!")
btn2.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=100)
 
# Start tkinter's main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you run the code? ```_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name```