# Python tkinter button text is not appearing

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tic tac toe game in Python tkinter. Every time I try to configure the button's text in the `click` function, the text isn't appearing. The strange thing about it is that when I type: `print(buttons_list[c][d].cget("text"))`after configuring the button, it prints what I set the text as, but the text itself doesn't appear on the button. Can someone help me fix this issue?
My code so far (unfinished):

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Tic Tac Toe")
screen.geometry("600x600+350+10")
buttons_list = []
clicked = []
turns = 0


def click(c, d):
    global turns
    turns += 1

    if turns % 2 == 0:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="X", fg="red")
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="O", fg="green")


x = -200
y = 0
for i in range(3):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        b = Button(screen, height=100, width=200, bg="papaya whip", command=lambda i=i, j=j: click(i, j))
        x += 200
        b.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(b)
    y += 200
    x = -200


screen.mainloop()
```

A big thanks to TheLizzard for helping me! Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Tic Tac Toe")
screen.geometry("600x600+350+10")
turns = 0


def click(c, d):
    global turns
    turns += 1

    if turns % 2 == 0:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="X", fg="red", font=("Arial", 50))
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="O", fg="green", font=("Arial", 50))


pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
buttons_list = []

for i in range(3):
    row = []
    for j in range(3):
        button = Button(screen, height=200, width=200, image=pixel, text=" ", compound="c", bg="papaya whip",
                        command=lambda i=i, j=j: click(i, j))
        button.grid(row=i, column=j)
        row.append(button)
    buttons_list.append(row)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: When you use `height=100, width=200`, it isn't in pixels. It's in characters. Try changing that to `height=1, width=3`.

Comment: The text appears on the buttons. Your buttons are too big for the screen. Decrease the size of the buttons, and you will see the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Tic Tac Toe")
screen.geometry("600x600+350+10")
turns = 0


def click(c, d):
    global turns
    turns += 1

    has_been_clicked = (buttons_list[c][d].cget("text") != " ")
    print(has_been_clicked)

    if turns % 2 == 0:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="X", fg="red")
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="O", fg="green")


pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
buttons_list = []

for i in range(3):
    row = []
    for j in range(3):
        button = Button(screen, height=200, width=200, image=pixel, text=" ", compound="c", bg="papaya whip", command=lambda i=i, j=j: click(i, j))
        button.grid(row=i, column=j)
        row.append(button)
    buttons_list.append(row)

screen.mainloop()
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286221/11106801) method to force the size of the buttons to be in pixels instead of characters. Also I used `.grid` to put the buttons in a grid. I also added a `has_been_clicked` variable inside the function so it will make it easier for you to implement the rest of the program.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!