# alphabet, number, special characters, how many pixels it takes up

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I use tkinter to make a few buttons, but when I use padx, pady to set size for buttons but it's not the same size. So, I think letters, numbers and special characters take up different numbers of pixels.

```
myButton1 = Button(root,fg= "red",bg="yellow", text="1",padx=100,pady=10,command=lambda:myClick(1))
myButton1.grid(column=0,row=1)

myButton4 = Button(root,fg= "red",bg="yellow", text="+",padx=100,pady=10,command=lambda:myClick(1))
myButton4.grid(column=0,row=2)

myButton5 = Button(root,fg= "red",bg="yellow", text="/",padx=100,pady=10,command=lambda:myClick(1))
myButton5.grid(column=0,row=2)
```

I try change padx.

````
myButton1 = Button(root,fg= "red",bg="yellow", text="1",padx=100,pady=10,command=lambda:myClick(1))
myButton1.grid(column=0,row=1)

myButton4 = Button(root,fg= "red",bg="yellow", text="413",padx=94,pady=10,command=lambda:myClick(1))
myButton4.grid(column=0,row=2)

myButton5 = Button(root,fg= "red",bg="yellow", text="+",padx=99,pady=10,command=lambda:myClick(1))
myButton5.grid(column=0,row=3)

myButton6 = Button(root,fg= "red",bg="yellow", text="+++++",padx=83,pady=10,command=lambda:myClick(1))
myButton6.grid(column=0,row=4)```
````

Comment: Use fixed-width fonts like Monospace , adjust padx and pady then use width parameter

Comment: `padx` and `pady` are *extra space* added to the widget, not the size of the widget.  Use `width` (in characters for text, pixels for image) option to set the size of the widget.

Comment: I'm learning from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5PfbC5ld-Q&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV&index=5  @acw1668

Comment: @vitamin01 Use something like the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46284901/11106801) question to resize all of the buttons to the pixel width.