# Is there a way to make tkinter widget attributes global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am making a simple calculator using Python and tkinter and I wanted to save code by making global attributes.

I would like to set default attributes instead of:

```
myButton = Button(self, text = "A", width = 50, height = 50);
myButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, width = 50, height = 50);
myButton = Button(self, text = "A", width = 50, height = 50);
myButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1);
myButton = Button(self, text = "A");
myButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2);
myButton = Button(self, text = "A");
myButton.grid(row = 0, column = 3);
```

I would like to make a default attribute for the `Button` widget. Any way to make that happen?

Comment: using global variables is usually not recommended. Also the variable myButton is being replaced every time in your code for a new button. So you don't keep an instance of the previous buttons.

Comment: You could define a `class MyButton(Button):`, and in its `__init__()` method you could supply custom options when calling `super().__init__()`.  You could then create instances of `MyButton` instead of `Button` to use those options.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki There is no problem with using global variables if you can keep track of them. For a simple calculator app a functional approach is fully understandable and global variables are even recommended. Also in this case, I can't see the point of keeping a reference to all `Button`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to create a dictionary of the arguments you want to use as defaults (like the `width` and `height` I assume), and pass them in as `**kwargs` to each `Button`

And (as @Sembei mentioned), if you need to retain references to each button, you have to use different names for each variable. I've changed them here as an example

```
# create a dictionary of the properties you want to share for each button
btn_props = {
    'width': 50,
    'height': 50,
    # add other args here as needed
}

# pass 'btn_props' in as keyword arguments (a.k.a. 'kwargs')
myButton1 = Button(self, text = "A", **btn_props);
myButton1.grid(row = 0, column = 0);
myButton2 = Button(self, text = "A", **btn_props);
myButton2.grid(row = 0, column = 1);
myButton3 = Button(self, text = "A", **btn_props);
myButton3.grid(row = 0, column = 2);
myButton4 = Button(self, text = "A", **btn_props);
myButton4.grid(row = 0, column = 3);
```

Another option is to create your own button class that inherits from `tk.Button`, but that's slightly more involved

User @TheLizzard has also raised another good point: buttons aren't sized in units of pixels. If you want to do that, the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284901/how-do-i-resize-buttons-in-pixels-tkinter) is a good solution!

Comment: You might also want to add a comment that `Button`'s `width` and `height` are measured in characters not pixels. So a height of 50 is half of my screen. For more info, you can link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46284901/11106801) question and its accepted answer

Comment: @TheLizzard That's a very good point to bring up! And I have that very same linked answer saved myself haha.